# how to include a file in php and still respect the relative links from that included file

Tags: php, include-path

I am experimenting in PHP and was wondering how I could do something like this

```
if (site is wordpress)
    include wordpress index.php;
```

in the wordpress file there is a line

`require('./wp-blog-header.php');`

that wont work because it throws me file not found error, it will work however if i change it to this

`require('wp-blog-header.php');`

then i don't get a problem and the page loads (well to some extend because the wp-blog-header.php loads in some other files that are relative to wp-blog-header.php so those don't get included or loaded).

Is there some way to trick PHP into keeping and respect the relative files?

EDIT: Included my code for better context of my question

```
if ($app['framework']['type'] && $app['cms']['type']) {    
    echo "Only a Framework or CMS can be loaded at a time...";    
} else {    
    if (is_file("./app/" . $cfg['application']['name'] . "/index.php")) {
        require_once "./app/" . $cfg['application']['name'] . "/index.php";
    } else {    
        if ($app['framework']['type']) {            
            echo "framework";
            //require_once "./app/" . $cfg['application']['name'] . "/" . $app['framework']['type'] . "/index.php";         
        } else if ($app['cms']['type']) {               
            if ($admin) {
                require_once "./app/" . $cfg['application']['name'] . "/" . $app['cms']['type'] . "/wp-admin/index.php";
            } else {                        
                $old_working_dir = getcwd();   // Remember where we are now.
                chdir("./app/" . $cfg['application']['name'] . "/" . $app['cms']['type'] . "/");            // 'Go into' the Wordpress directory.
                //include("index.php");          // Include the index.php file (no need for 'wordpress/')
                chdir($old_working_dir); 
                require_once "index.php";
            }
        } else {    
            echo "There is no index in your project directory, if your going to use a Framework or CMS please choose one from the following, thank you (list of cms's and frameworks)";
        }
    }    
    exit;
}
```

Comment: filename, for example include("some-other-file.php')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd) to get the current working directory and [`chdir()`](http://php.net/chdir) to set it. In your case, it'd look something like this:

```
$old_working_dir = getcwd();   // Remember where we are now.
chdir("wordpress");            // 'Go into' the Wordpress directory.
include("index.php");          // Include the index.php file (no need for 'wordpress/')
chdir($old_working_dir);       // Go back to the previous directory.
```

Or:

```
chdir("wordpress");
include("index.php");
chdir("../");                  // Go back up one level.
```

Comment: oh, i have never been introduce to that. Let me try. I update the question with my actual code.

Comment: that actually works!, grant it that i can't user the require function but only the include to get it work. Thank you

Comment: In your posted code, you're changing the working directory back (with `chdir()`) to the original directory and then you use `require`. Switch those two lines around, or else the `chdir()` calls have no use, because you set it and then immediately revert the change.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better define a constant containing the path to your application and prepend that to every include you do:

```
define("APP_PATH", "/var/www/app/");

...

include(APP_PATH . 'foo/bar.php');
```

Comment: the problem with that is the wordpress has their on constants defined for their relative files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into PHP's magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)?

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory. (Added in PHP 5.3.0.)

If you're using an older version of PHP, you can use `dirname(__FILE__)`

Here's a small usage example:

```
/** 
 * file hierarchy
 * ./index.php
 * ./foo/bar.php
 * ./foo/baz.php
 */

// ./foo/bar.php
include __DIR__.'baz.php';

// ./index.php
include __DIR__.'/foo/bar.php';
```

You could now include `index.php` and in theory these includes should still work. It's also a less hackish solution compared to other answers.

Comment: the problem is that i dont want to change the dirname() function that  wordpress uses, but rather load the entire directory into my workspace. so the url looks like ww.foo.bar/index.php (which will actually load to www.foo.bar/wordpress/index.php)